# WAMP Apache not starting up

Tags: apache, wamp

I've trawled through the boards but cant find a solution to my problem.

I've run a netstat, and nothing else is using port 80. I have disabled every bit of security on my system, just to be doubly sure nothing is stopping it.

MySQL boots up just fine, but Apache does not start up. Using the built in port 80 tester also says that port 80 is clear, but when I click the start service button on Apache in WAMP nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: start -> run -> eventvwr.msc look for application log a check error.Or check apache's log file.Reson is sure there :)

Comment: apache's error log doesn't have anything since october 3rd. In event viewer though I do have 2 errors, I'll take a look at those, thanks
EDIT: looks like I had somehow put a C program I had been working on in the alias folder, not sure how but, apache was trying to run that and erroring as it was only a partially completed program. Thanks for the help

Comment: Happened to me too and it was Skype who was catching port 80. so if anyone encounter this might be his solution.

Answer (score 11):

Run **cmd.exe** as administrator. Then execute:

```
httpd -t
httpd -k start
```

Are there any error messages displayed?

If not, temporarily disable any firewall and anti-virus software you have. Try again.

If you're still not getting any error messages, uninstall your WAMP and try one of the other distributions - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Comment: hey, I found rkosegi comment above the best answer to this question, but thanks for your solution as well

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem but I have resolved it by logging out of Skpe, stopping Skype's service called Skype C2C Service and started wampapache Service. After I started wampserver, I then logged in Skype After. Both Skype and amperver work well after this process

Comment: If you were able to run WAMP previously, and it no longer worked, Skype is definitely the culprit!

Answer (score 0):

Ok just do one thing. If you are running skype then close it. restart all services, It might work as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some times this occurs when Windows Event log Service is disabled.
I recently faced the same problem,and browsed various answers around web in vain.
But later I remembered that I disabled Windows Event Log Service in Oder to run a game smoothly.So I Enabled that service again and now every thing is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install vcredist_x86.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

Answer (score 0):

I opened up services.msc from the command prompt and disabled SQL Server reporting services

& SQL Server analysis services. These services were using port 80.

Then I restarted WAMP Server and it started working properly as before.

Answer (score 0):

Check **DocumentRoot** directory location if it exists.

> DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem just following the below steps. Hope this will help to you.

1. Go to `Wamp/Apach/httpd.conf`
2. Under `httpd.conf` search for `Listen` in my case its `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`
3. Just change the last digit that means your Listen will be `Listen 0.0.0.0:81`
4. Save the file, after that start Apache

Thanks,
Amzad

Answer (score 0):

From time to time, with the updates, Microsoft set the 'World Wide Web Publishing Service' startup type to 'Auto'. Try to see if that is your case.

<kbd>Right-click</kbd> on your Start button to open the WinX Menu. Select *Run*. This opens the Run box. Now type `services.msc` in it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Services Manager.

Locate that service and edit with <kbd>double-clik</kbd> then set the startup type to 'Disable' to avoid it comes into conflict.

Answer (score -1):

hi the solution is simple.
all you have to do is to right click on wampserver icon on the taskbar and select exit.
after doing that right click on the wampserver.exe icon and select run as administrator option from the context menu.
that's it.
it will solve your problem

Comment: Hey @Vishal, you may have gotten downvoted for this, but this answer solved my problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad I could help @MattWest :)